# How to open a single popup in React on click and pass props to it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly inexperienced in React, so I'm building a Jeopardy game in it. Right now, my idea is to open a popup by clicking on the boxes on the Jeopardy board and displaying the clue of the clicked box component in the popup. I don't want to have multiple popups for each clue, since I just want the popup to update its contents with the specific clue selected.

I'm stuck on how to implement this, I initially attempted this by including the BoardPopup component in the BoardClue component, but that didn't seem to be an ideal way of doing this as it obviously just created multiple popups.

My idea is to click the BoardClue component and pass the clue props to a single BoardPopup component.

```
function BoardPopup(props) {
  return (
    <div className="popup">
      {props.clue}
    </div>
  );
}

class BoardClue extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showPopup: false
    }
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      showPopup: !this.state.showPopup
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="board-clue" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <div>${this.props.value}</div>
        <div style={{display:'none'}}>{this.props.clue}</div>
        <div style={{display:'none'}}>{this.props.answer}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The render function of the Board component. Questions are fetched from a JSON file and mapped into BoardClue components.

```
  render() {
    const error = this.state.error;
    const isLoaded = this.state.isLoaded;
    const questions = this.state.data.questions;

    if (error) {
      return <div>Error {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    } else {
      const clues = questions.map((question, index) => {
        return (
          <BoardClue key={index} value={question.value} clue={question.clue} answer={question.answer} />
        );
      });
      return (
        <div className="board">
          {clues}
        </div>
      );

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want only one popup then it should be a child of <Board /> and not of <BoardClue />. You could still open it from the latter by passing a handleClick prop to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways and libraries that can help you build a modal, but, you can do it just with React and CSS. Here is my take on your case:

[CodeSandbox - Board Popup](https://codesandbox.io/embed/board-popup-7tyir)

Using `React.useState` We generate the local state to manage the `Popup` visibility. We toggle it by clicking on the question boxes. The overlay `div` is to bring the `Panel` in to focus and to make it impossible to click another box. To close it you can click on the `overlay` or the `clue`.

Please check [React's Hooks documentation page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) to learn how to use them. They are not the only way to handle state, but it's one of the easiest.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a genius! :D